# how bot builder chat bot communicate with local machine files

Tags: c#, asp.net, botframework

I need to access some files from local machine from bot builder chat bot using c#. I tried Process.Start but it worked fine locally not for messenger channel

Comment: do you mean the computer the bot is hosted on or the computer of the user?

Comment: bot is hosted in azure but file is in local machine.. so how it ll access the file at hosted level

Comment: Please try this one, I did the same thing: [How to debug Azure BOT service from visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081339/how-to-debug-azure-bot-service-from-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) with proper instance for your file.

Comment: proper instance means?? how i ll connect my local machine instance to it

Comment: https://ngrok.com/docs#expose follow this link.  Instructions on how to properly set it up are there.

Comment: no it is showing error as 501. Internal server error.. I need to access file which is in local machine.. I am running code as  Process.Start("C:/ex.vbs") when it get response message as "show file".. when i run this, it is executing at localhost but after hosting in azure and trying to access from messenger then it is showing error as 501. Internal server error for the Process.Start code.. please help me to solve the error

Comment: You must run your project on your local machine first. Then use ngrok to make your local address public.

Comment: I already run in local machine.. it is running properly... how I have to run in messenger tht is my qus.. how I have my make my address public using n grok..

Comment: i need to run ex.vbs file this file will contain code to open an notepad.. so to access this file i wrote code as  if(activity.Text.Contains("Reset my password"))
 {
    await context.PostAsync($"Robot is opening notepad for you!! wait for a while..");
      Process.Start("C:\\CB.vbs");
            }                                                                                                        this code works fine (means opens notepad in my desktop) when i run it as localhost:3939 in bot framework emulator  but after hosting  in internet it is not working throwing error 501.

Comment: How i can run my ex.vbs file at localhost because in localhost i can run only html or php files.. if i dont have localhost address for ex.vbs then ngrok wont provide any public ip.. please help me to solve this